# UITableView section header overlap the customized headerView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have trying to resize the view or add constrains but not work.
[image]

[image]

This is the code not work:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 100;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //self.mainViewTableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0.1)];
    if (section == 0) {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, tableView.frame.size.width, 100)];
        //[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:240/255.0 blue:240/255.0 alpha:1]];
        [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self.mainViewTableView setTableHeaderView:view];
        return view;
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }

}
```

But when I try this, it works find.(This is not I want, I want add header view in storyboard but not add it programmatically.)

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, 300)];
//[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:240/255.0 blue:240/255.0 alpha:1]];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.mainViewTableView setTableHeaderView:view];
```

Comment: did you find the solution ...

Answer (score 5):

set zPosition of view what you created in tableView viewForHeaderInSection

swift version:

```
sectionView.layer.zPosition = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of headers in tableview:

- main tableview header, displaying on the top;
- section header, displaying in every section.

If you want to use section header loaded from storyboard, you should declare iboutlet property of UIView or subclass and add it to your vc in IB, like so:

[image]

To add tableHeaderView in IB, just drop it in the top of your tableView:

[image]

Comment: I want to use main tableview header in storyboar, but section header overlap the main header like the screenshot, how to do with that?

Comment: If you do not need any section header, just one tableHeaderView - than you don't need to override this delegate method: -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{